# Regex to find all matches

Tags: java, regex

I need a regex to find all matches for my pattern.

The text is something like this:

```
"someother text !style_delete [company code : 43ev4] between text !style_delete [organiztion : 0asj9] end of line text"
```

And I would like to find all matches for the pattern:

```
!style_delete [.*]
```

I have tried like this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("!style_delete\\s*\\[.*\\]");
```

With this the match text is coming like this:

```
!style_delete [company code : 43ev4] between text !style_delete [organiztion : 0asj9]
```

But I am expected as follows:

```
match 1 : !style_delete [company code : 43ev4] 
match 2 : !style_delete [organiztion : 0asj9]
```

Please help me, what will the regex in java to get above output.

Comment: Could you please provide an example of text that you are trying to match?

Comment: You could replace the `.*` in the brackets with `[^]]*`. This will match everything inside of the square brackets instead of the right square bracket so you don't accidentally consume too much.

Comment: To try your regexp patterns, you can always use some online regexp testers (google "online regexp" to have a few). I often use https://regex101.com

Comment: A regular expression has to be between forward slashes like /regexp*/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
@Test
public void test() {
    final String input = "someother text !style_delete [company code : 43ev4] between text !style_delete [organiztion : 0asj9] end of line text";
    // my regexp:strong text
    // final String regex = "(!style_delete\\s\\[[a-zA-Z0-9\\s:]*\\])";
    // regexp from Trinmon:
    final String regex = "(!style_delete\\s*\\[[^\\]]*\\])";

    final Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input);

    final List<String> matches = new ArrayList<>();
    while (m.find()) {
        matches.add(m.group(0));
    }

    assertEquals(2, matches.size());
    assertEquals("match 1: ", matches.get(0), "!style_delete [company code : 43ev4]");
    assertEquals("match 2: ", matches.get(1), "!style_delete [organiztion : 0asj9]");
}
```

**edit**

perhaps the pattern from Trinimon's answer is a little bit more elegant. i updated the regex with the regex of him.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use [non-greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) matching:

```
start.*?end
```

In your case, pattern is :

```
!style_delete\\s\\[(.*?)\\] (Even simple to understand than first version :))
```

Proof (Java 7) :

```
String string = "someother text !style_delete [company code : 43ev4] between text !style_delete [organiztion : 0asj9] end of line text"; 
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("!style_delete\\s\\[(.*?)\\]");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string) ;
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Link to proof : http://ideone.com/Qtymb3

Answer (score 3):

It's because `.*` is greedy. Use this instead:

```
"!style_delete\\s*\\[[^\\]]*\\]"
```

It means: match everything in bracket excluding a closing `]`.

Or make the content between `[]` it non-greedy:

```
"!style_delete\\s*\\[.*?\\]"
```